# calculate duration of time interval while removing certain time spans

Tags: r, lubridate

Assume we have an interval spanning several days (interval "A" in Figure below).

```
library(lubridate)
int <- interval("2018-01-01 22:00:00", "2018-01-04 10:00:00")
```

In hours, I get

```
as.period(int, unit = "hours")
"60H 0M 0S"
```

Now, I want to subtract all non-working-hours, here 16:00-08:00 (greyed out) in that interval, i.e. only keep the blue parts (08:00-16:00) and, again, calculate the remaining hours (see "B" in Figure below), which would be 8 + 8 + 2 = 18 hours.

[image]

One approach would be to create a list of intervals I want to keep which span the entire interval and then calculate intersections. (The code below could, of course, be setup programmatically using floor/ceiling/seq functions etc.)

```
int_keep <- list(
  interval("2018-01-01 08:00:00", "2018-01-01 16:00:00"),
  interval("2018-01-02 08:00:00", "2018-01-02 16:00:00"),
  interval("2018-01-03 08:00:00", "2018-01-03 16:00:00"),
  interval("2018-01-04 08:00:00", "2018-01-04 16:00:00"),
  interval("2018-01-05 08:00:00", "2018-01-05 16:00:00")
)

l <- lapply(int_keep, function(x) intersect(x, int))
mns <- sapply(l, as.numeric)    # returns seconds
sum(mns, na.rm = T) / 60 / 60   # sum of intersections in hours
[1] 18
```

**While this works, it appears utterly clumsy to me. What would be a less tedious way to do this?**

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(DateTime=seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2018-01-01 22:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2018-01-04 10:00:00"), by = "1 hour"))
head(df)
#DateTime
#1 2018-01-01 22:00:00
#2 2018-01-01 23:00:00
#3 2018-01-02 00:00:00
#4 2018-01-02 01:00:00
#5 2018-01-02 02:00:00
#6 2018-01-02 03:00:00

#you want the hours worked between A and B
A <-format(strptime("8:00:00", "%H:%M:%S"),"%H:%M:%S")
B <-format(strptime("16:00:00", "%H:%M:%S"),"%H:%M:%S")
#a simple ifelse statement to assign a value of 1 to column "value" if the time is between 8 and 16 or a 0 if it's not: 
df$value<-ifelse((format(df[1],"%H:%M:%S")>A & format(df[1],"%H:%M:%S")<=B),1,0)
 tail(df)
 #DateTime DateTime
 #56 2018-01-04 05:00:00        0
 #57 2018-01-04 06:00:00        0
 #58 2018-01-04 07:00:00        0
 #59 2018-01-04 08:00:00        0
 #60 2018-01-04 09:00:00        1
 #61 2018-01-04 10:00:00        1
#now taking the column sum of the value column will give you the total hours worked: 
TotalHoursWorked<-colSums(df$value)
TotalHoursWorked
#DateTime 
 # 18
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I only used full hours in my interval example for the sake of simplicity. The solution should be generic, i.e. work for arbitrary time intervals (e.g .8:15:10 - 16:01:00). But I reckon, one could just simply move to seconds in the Posix Sequence you create to achieve this. The downside would be that checking seconds over e.g. one year needs 31 million entries and is thus computationally quite expensive and slow. Nonetheless, your approach is very useful in some cases. However, I am wondering if there is something more direct.